# What kind of access flash has to our systems?

Tags: security, flash

It seems like there is major security issue found in flash every other week or so. There was another one just yesterday.
This and being closed source, I can't help but wonder, what kind of access it has exactly to a system.
Is it sandboxed to just the browser or can go out of it as well?
Since it can be included in every site without even knowing, you might have an active instance of it at pretty much any time. 
So, what exactly it can do to our systems? Hypothetically.